# Sidekiq on same host as Ruby app

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I have a ruby app deployed on a server and redis on another server.  What are the pros and cons of deploying sidekiq on same server as ruby app?

Answer (score 3):

Probably better for Serverfault...

But the biggest pro for keeping them separate is that you can scale your application servers and point them all to your redis server, so you can more easily scale your application horizontally.

When you've got both on a single server, it might be a bit easier/cheaper to manage, but you'll never be able to scale it separately and Redis will be eating a bit of your RAM that your application won't be able to use.